# Mandrill templates still tracking open and click rates after disabling in API

Tags: ruby, mailchimp, mandrill

Trying to figure out why some mandrill templates are still tracking open and click rates, when in the our API, we have disabled both `track_opens` and `track_clicks`.

Per the [Mandrill, How does open tracking work?](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582907-How-does-open-tracking-work-)  if you set these parameters it will override any account settings for tracking.

**So I am trying to figure out if there is something that I am missing with possible account settings on a per template bases?**

```
  message = {
    subject: subject, global_merge_vars: global_merge_vars, merge_vars: to_email_hashes.map { |hash|
      hash[:merge_vars][:vars] = _hash_to_mandrill_vars(hash[:merge_vars][:vars])
      hash[:merge_vars]
    },
    from_email: _from_email_mask(from_email), from_name: from_name, to: to_email_hashes.map { |hash| {name: hash[:name], email: hash[:email]} },
    headers: {}, preserve_recipients: false, track_opens: false, track_clicks: false,
    attachments: attachments.map { |hash| {name: hash[:name], type: hash[:type], content: _encode_attachment(hash[:content])} }
  }
```